# Download Android .apk from Firebase (APP Distribution) with Gitlab, to run e2e automated tests

Tags: android, firebase, gitlab, apk, gitlab-ci

We are looking for a way to download from Gitlab an Android .apk that was distributed via Firebase and is located in the (APP Distribution) section, to upload it to an e2e automated test repository and run those tests against the downloaded .apk.

Is there any way to do this? In the Firebase page I can only find the way to upload it to Firebase via CLI, but not the way to download it.

Does anyone have any ideas or have done anything similar?

```
firebase:
    stage: firebase
    image: node:latest
    script:
        - npm i -g firebase-tools
        - firebase --help
        - firebase projects:list --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
        - firebase apps:list --project escript-app-63c00 --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
        - ?????
        - curl -O "here would go the URL of the downloadable .apk"
```

How can I access one of these apps lists and download an .apk or .ipa?

Comment: Based on the response in your answer, I'd like to "vote" for this too. How did you raise your request to Firebase please and I'll mimic what you did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Firebase Response**

"*Currently, you can only download the uploaded .ipa and .apk file from the Firebase console. There's an internal request filed for having it possible to download the files via Firebase CLI. As an action, I’ve raised your case to have it considered a "vote" for having this possible, however, I won’t be able to provide specific details or timelines as to when this could materialize. For now, you may keep an eye out for updates on our official blog and release notes for newly added products, features, and SDKs.
You may also check out on the following documentations for the currently available App Distribution commands:*

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#appdistro-commands
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-cli

"